# "Esperimenti a cui aveva preso parte" oppure "esperimenti cui aveva preso parte"?

Tags: word-usage, grammar, prepositions, pronouns

Quale tra queste due frasi è la forma corretta"

> - Enrico Fermi morì di un cancro dovuto forse agli esperimenti *a cui* aveva preso parte a Los Alamos.
> - Enrico Fermi morì di un cancro dovuto forse agli esperimenti *cui* aveva preso parte a Los Alamos.

Comment: I'm not sure but I'd say that both are correct since it is being used as a _complemento di termine_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sono entrambe corrette, la forma con il "cui" da solo è un po' più letteraria.
Come dice [la Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cui/)

> Nei casi nei quali è usato come compl. di termine si può usare anche
>   senza la preposizione a: la persona cui mi sono rivolto;
>
> ...
>
> Esclusivam. letter. è l’uso senza prep., come compl. di termine (Voi
>   cui fortuna ha posto in mano il freno ..., Petrarca) o come compl.
>   ogg. (Al passegger, cui semivivo e nudo Lascia in breve tra’ sassi,
>   Leopardi).

Da notare che:

- nei casi in cui *non è* complemento di termine, la preposizione non si può omettere: *il libro **di** cui ti ho parlato*, *l'obiettivo **per** cui hai combattuto*, etc.
- se si usano "[il/la quale]/[i/le quali]" invece di "cui" come complementi indiretti, la preposizione è obbligatoria (anche quando è complemento di termine): *gli esperimenti ai quali aveva preso parte* (sbagliato: <s>gli esperimenti i quali aveva preso parte</s>)

Comment: La ragione è etimologica: *cui* è il dativo del pronome latino *qui* e l'italiano *cui* viene direttamente da lì.